# MVC Same Action Name POST method call goes to GET Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have two Action Method

```
[HttpGet]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        [ActionName("Assignments")]
        public ActionResult Assignments()
        {
        }
```

and

```
  [ActionName("Assignments")]
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Assignments(int x)
        {
        }
```

i have @html.Actionlink which is suppoe to invoke above POST method but it invokes GET method. Inspite of having [HttpPost] attribute.

When i fire a request from Postman it works correctly but it is failing from @Html.ActionLink

Comment: cany you show your actionlink code??

Comment: ActionLinks don't fire POST requests, they fire GET requests. You can still pass parameters to an action that handles GET requests in the same way that you are attempting.

Comment: i have below code in my partial view within a BeginForm                  
        <dd class="@Model.Item3Css">@Html.ActionLink(Model.Item3Display, Model.TargetActionName, Model.TargetControllerName, new { filter = Model.Item3Value, view = Model.ViewType }, new { })</dd>

Comment: @MikeC. is correct - `ActionLink` fire GET requests. If you want to post, then use a `submit` input or button

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can not generate POST links with @Html.ActionLink. You would need to use a form with @Html.BeginForm or @Ajax.BeginForm.

Answer (score 0):

Use as

```
  [ActionName("Assignments/{x}")]
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assignments(int x)
    {
    }
```

Comment: In realtime actually i have  public ActionResult Assignments(class x,int? y) so will it be like [ActionName("Assignments/{x}/{y}")

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by writing a Custom ajax call in the same cshtml file and it started invoking.